# Codeigniter join, group by and count a row from one table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm struggling a bit with this code to get the count result from book_listing (totally) which is the total count of bookings. From the result, some are correct but some are multiplied by 3 or so.

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->where('list_status', 1)
         ->where('list_date >=', date('Y-m-d'))
         ->order_by("user_listings.list_created", "desc")
         ->limit(18, null)
         ->select('*, COUNT(user_bookings.book_listing) as totally')
         ->from('user_listings')
         ->join('user_images', 'user_images.img_listing = user_listings.list_reference')
         ->join('user_states', 'user_states.state_id = user_listings.list_state')
         ->join('user_bookings', 'user_bookings.book_listing = user_listings.list_reference', 'left')
         ->group_by('user_listings.list_reference')
         ->get();
```

Thanks to any help :)

Comment: You have non-aggregate fields (*) along with an aggregate function and `GROUP BY` clause... that's really dangerous if you don't know what you're doing. I would suggest adding the result of `$this->db->last_query();` so people can help you with the query a little more easily.

Comment: @kchason thanks for the feedback. I did the $this->db->last_query(); and here is the result: https://gist.github.com/charlesmudy/4a59fdc2549cc7619ddbf7387c8b05f1

Comment: Do you remove left join and check with inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it, the `user_images` table seems to be causing the issue due to multiple images being fetched while I need it to return only one.

```
$this->db->where('list_status', 1)
         ->where('list_date >=', date('Y-m-d'))
         ->order_by("user_listings.list_created", "desc")
         ->limit(18, null)
         ->select('user_listings.*,image.*,user_states.*')
         ->select('COUNT(user_bookings.book_listing) as totalBooked')
         ->from('user_listings')
         ->join('user_bookings', 'user_bookings.book_listing = user_listings.list_reference', 'left')
         ->join('(SELECT * FROM user_images WHERE user_images.img_key IN(SELECT MIN(user_images.img_key) FROM user_images GROUP BY user_images.img_listing)) AS image',
                                            'image.img_listing = user_listings.list_reference')
         ->join('user_states', 'user_states.state_id = user_listings.list_state')
         ->group_by('user_listings.list_reference')
         ->get();
```

Basically, I had to do a select from the join table for `user_images`. Hope it helps someone else :)